# Tor bridges all blocked (Cannot connect) (Smoothwall HTTPS Interception)

Tags: bridge, proxy, censorship, ip-address, blocked

I have attempted to connect to the tor network through all manner of bridges including from directly requested from bridgedb but still cannot connect

```
4/28/21, 01:21:07.362 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/21, 01:21:07.362 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/21, 01:21:07.362 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/21, 01:21:07.362 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/21, 01:21:07.362 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/21, 01:21:07.362 [WARN] Cannot find maximum file descriptor, assuming: 256
4/28/21, 01:21:08.580 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 1% (conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport
4/28/21, 01:21:08.590 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 2% (conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport
4/28/21, 01:21:08.630 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:08.740 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:08.740 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:08.760 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 51.222.13.177:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=5EDAC3B810E12B01F6FD8050D2FD3E277B289A08 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:08.760 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:08.610 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
4/28/21, 01:21:08.886 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
4/28/21, 01:21:09.590 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.660 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.670 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.670 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.670 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 51.222.13.177:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=5EDAC3B810E12B01F6FD8050D2FD3E277B289A08 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.738 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.881 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:09.926 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:10.670 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:10.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:10.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 51.222.13.177:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=5EDAC3B810E12B01F6FD8050D2FD3E277B289A08 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:10.412 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:10.420 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:11.650 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:11.730 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:11.750 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:11.770 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 51.222.13.177:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=5EDAC3B810E12B01F6FD8050D2FD3E277B289A08 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:12.810 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:12.820 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/21, 01:21:12.820 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
```

Update: The network uses Smoothwall HTTPS interception

Comment: Are you in a country that is known to block Tor access?

Comment: The network which I have to use blocks tor access

Comment: It sounds like the Smoothwall system [only allows HTTP on port 80 and HTTPS on port 443](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9992670). Unfortunately I'm not aware of any pluggable transports / proxies that you can use that make traffic appear as HTTPS on port 443. Maybe if you add the "Smoothwall HTTPS interception" into your post title, other people might see it and be able to help.

Comment: @Steve actually Smoothwall HTTPS interception has a method to block Tor traffic that goes through port 80 and 443. So that won't work. See: https://kb.smoothwall.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002033490-Blocking-Tor-Using-Smoothwall-Filter-Firewall

Comment: How can Smoothwall block ports 80 and 443 wouldn't that block access to the internet outright?

Comment: @opiudf it only blocks tor connections to those ports, it doesn't block those ports outright.